# Convert string in scientific notation to number format in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this String:

```
8.1161E-002
```

This string is actually a result of a calculation (unfortunately the result is converted to string and I can't change it).

So how could I convert this String to a format like `00.081`?

I'm looking at XPath reference but I can't find a `format()` function for example. Is there a way of doing this in XPath?

Comment: In XPath 2.0 number() which will give you 0.081161 but in XPath 1.0 it will not be recognized as number and give you NaN. I don't think there is a ways of doing this with pure XPath 1.0. Where's that value comming from, can you fix it on that end?

Comment: It comes from another system so I can't change it there. I tried number() and it does give me NaN as result. So there;s no way of solving this with pure XPath 1.0?

Comment: @Dalek you can also use `format-number()` XSLT function.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way... @alecxe in XSLT 1.0 format-number() would return NaN too.

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz thanks, then probably the only way would be to process it afterwards in the non-xpath code.

Comment: In an XSLT 1.0 context, this could be solved using the EXSLT extension function `math:power` together with `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### XPath 1.0 solution

If you are stuck with *XPath 1.0* and your input is of the form (*mantissa* **E+** *exponent*) or (*mantissa* **E-** *exponent*) you can use this **hack** (which is not very nice but gets the job done):

```
translate(
     concat(
           number(substring('100000000000000',1,number(substring-after(/number,'E+'))+1))*number(substring-before(/number,'E+')),
           number(concat(substring('0.00000000000000',1,number(substring-after(/number,'E-'))+1),'1'))*number(substring-before(/number,'E-')),
           number(substring('100000000000000',1,number(substring-after(/number,'e+'))+1))*number(substring-before(/number,'e+')),
           number(concat(substring('0.00000000000000',1,number(substring-after(/number,'e-'))+1),'1'))*number(substring-before(/number,'e-')),
           /number[not(contains(.,'E')) and not(contains(.,'e'))]
     ), 'Na', ''
)
```

It extracts the *mantissa* (string before the `E` or `e`) and then obtains a fraction or power of 10 by shifting a string of zeros the amount of *positions* determined by the *exponent*, Then it multiplies this with the *mantissa*. It deals separately with the case of positive or negative exponents. Since there is no *if* in XPath, it concatenates both results as strings, and allows one of them to produce 'NaN, which is removed later.

For example, if the *exponent* is `+2` it will get the `100` substring from the first or third string. If it is `+5` it will get `10000` and if it is `-3` it will extract the `0.001` substring from the second or fourth strings. It then will multiply that number with the *mantissa*.

Since you will either have `e+` or `e-`, one of them will be the string `NaN` which is then removed from the final string using the `translate` function (it removes all `N` and `a` characters, which never occur in decimal numbers or scientific notation). The last `concat` argument deals with the case where the number is *not* in scientific notation.

The **e** can be in upper or lower case.

**Limitations:**

1. It *won't* work if you have positive exponents *without* the `+`
2. It will show incorrect results if the absolute value of the exponent is larger than 15.
3. It also will fail if you have hexadecimal values (since any `a` will be removed from the final result).

Applying it to this file:

```
<number>2.34</number>
```

it will read normally as:

```
2.34
```

But `2.34e+5` will be read as `234000` and `2.34E-005` will become `0.0000234`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Question: How would this solution deal with "correct" inputs? For example when value = "10". It's tricky because I can't use an if statement in xpath 1.0.

Comment: I fixed it. Now it deals with both scientific notation and "plain" numbers. I also made it simpler using `translate()`.

Comment: Omg, this is really crazy! You are an xpath genius :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function number(). This works with xpath 2.0.

Here is an example of how it would work.

XML

```
<this>
<stuff>8.1161E-002</stuff>
</this>
```

Xpath

```
/this/number(stuff)
```

Result

`0.081161`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on Xpath > 1.0. Just for completeness I solved mine with:

xs:decimal(sum(/a/b))

Works fine

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, [Sauer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52061749) has solved my problem. The line below was returning 
3.00375e2. With xs:decimal now I get 300.375.

```
/products/xs:decimal(avg(product[contains(name/text(),"Microprocessor")]/price))
```

If you want to limit the number of decimals, you can use the round function, as follows:

```
/products/round(xs:decimal(avg(product[contains(name/text(),"Microprocessor")]/price))*100) div 100
```